# Html/Bootstrap - The whole body hides when it is clicked on the checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap template that has special and beautiful check boxes and switches.
I made the whole theme from ltr to rtl (for Persian language) and I have added "direction: rtl" class to my pages. After this when I click on a switch or check box the whole section disappears (top navbar and sidebar remains constant). 
How can I fix this problem?
I have added pictures:
[image: before clicking]

[image: after changing switch]

this is demo of my code:
[DEMO](http://www.msh-dev.ir/sample/tranpars/cp-user/new-order.php)

I have tested it on google chrome and it works well but in Firefox it has the problem!

Comment: We need to see the code to be able to help you. After all elements turned invisible, what does your browser's developement tool say? Where are they? Do they have `display: none;`?

Comment: There is a lot of codes and takes a lot of time to separate them, I will upload whole template and link it .

Comment: Well either you take the time to separate the important code from the other code or we have to. And the later significantly decreases your chance for an answer. Please [provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can use inspect elements to see codes you need. I will upload and check it if it was useless I will separate codes.

Comment: I have added the demo link and updated question. Please check switch buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix it by making whole body `ltr` and just adding a new div with `rtl` direction. This works for me, and it was because of framework I use (I didn't used bootstrap for this part!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name or id of the field.

Comment: It hasn't any id or name attributes. Its just class and if I delete class I will lose that bootstrap style!